# Uploading a Folder to GDrive and get the Folder ID to use to upload files

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

Thanks for reading my question. I am working on the google drive api and can upload files from a text blob to the google drive. However, I need to add the folder ID manually and for users to use this and not get an error since they are trying to upload it into *my* folder. How can I create or just get a folder ID - maybe even upload to the root GDrive directory ? Any tips would be helpful.

Thanks

```
// Global vars
const SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';
const gdResponse = document.querySelector('#response');
const login = document.querySelector('#login');
const authStatus = document.querySelector('#auth-status');
const textWrap = document.querySelector('.textWrapper');
const addFolder = document.querySelector('#createFolder');
const uploadBtn = document.querySelector('#uploadFile');

// Save Button and Function
uploadBtn.addEventListener('click', uploadFile);

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log('Loading init when page loads');
  // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
  // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
  gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
});

function initClient() {
  const discoveryUrl =
    'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest';

  // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
  // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
  // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.
  gapi.client
    .init({
      apiKey: 'My-API-Key',
      clientId:
        'My-Client-ID',
      discoveryDocs: [discoveryUrl],
      scope: SCOPE,
    })
    .then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);


// Actual upload of the file to GDrive
function uploadFile() {
  let accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token; // Google Drive API Access Token
  console.log('Upload Blob - Access Token: ' + accessToken);

  let fileContent = document.querySelector('#content').value; // As a sample, upload a text file.
  console.log('File Should Contain : ' + fileContent);
  let file = new Blob([fileContent], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  let metadata = {
    name: 'Background Sync ' + date, // Filename
    mimeType: 'text/plain', // mimeType at Google Drive

    // For Testing Purpose you can change this File ID to a folder in your Google Drive
    parents: ['Manually-entered-Folder-ID'], // Folder ID in Google Drive
     // I'd like to have this automatically filled with a users folder ID
  };

  let form = new FormData();
  form.append(
    'metadata',
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' })
  );
  form.append('file', file);

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    'post',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id'
  );
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(
      'Upload Successful to GDrive: File ID Returned - ' + xhr.response.id
    ); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
    gdResponse.innerHTML =
      'Uploaded File. File Response ID : ' + xhr.response.id;
  };
  xhr.send(form);
}
```

I didn't include some of the unrelated stuff. I have something like this for the uploading of a folder and it's not working unsurprisingly.

```
function createFolder() {
  var fileMetadata = {
    name: 'WordQ-Backups',
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
  };
  drive.files.create(
    {
      resource: fileMetadata,
      fields: 'id',
    },
    function (err, file) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Folder Id: ', file.id);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to upload a file to the root folder or the created new folder.

For this, how about the following modification patterns?

### Pattern 1:

When you want to put the file to the root folder, please try the following modification.

#### From:

```
parents: ['Manually-entered-Folder-ID'],
```

#### To:

```
parents: ['root'],
```

or, please remove `parents: ['Manually-entered-Folder-ID'],`. By this, the file is created to the root folder.

### Pattern 2:

When you want to create new folder and put the file to the created folder, please try the following modification. In your script, unfortunately, I'm not sure about `drive` in `createFolder()` from your question. So I cannot understand about the issue of your `createFolder()`. So in this pattern, the folder is created with `XMLHttpRequest`.

#### Modified script:

```
function createFile(accessToken, folderId) {
  console.log('File Should Contain : ' + fileContent);
  let fileContent = document.querySelector('#content').value;
  console.log('File Should Contain : ' + fileContent);
  let file = new Blob([fileContent], { type: 'application/pdf' });

  let metadata = {
    name: 'Background Sync ' + date,
    mimeType: 'text/plain',
    parents: [folderId], // <--- Modified
  };
  let form = new FormData();
  form.append(
    'metadata',
    new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], { type: 'application/json' })
  );
  form.append('file', file);
  
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(
    'post',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id'
  );
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(
      'Upload Successful to GDrive: File ID Returned - ' + xhr.response.id
    );
    gdResponse.innerHTML =
      'Uploaded File. File Response ID : ' + xhr.response.id;
  };
  xhr.send(form);
}

function createFolder(accessToken) {
  const folderName = "sample"; // <--- Please set the folder name.
  
  let metadata = {
    name: folderName,
    mimeType: 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
  };
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?fields=id');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const folderId = xhr.response.id;
    console.log(folderId);
    createFile(accessToken, folderId);
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(metadata));
}

// At first, this function is run.
function uploadFile() {
  let accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
  createFolder(accessToken);
}
```

### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank You!

Comment: @matt Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: No problem, I was at the cottage for the weekend so sorry for delay. I'm not a big stack overflow user so if I missed giving you points or w.e I apologize. I upvoted and selected your answer as the correct solution

Comment: @matt Thank you so much for your support!